# Call for question titles: Mathematical modeling/applied mathematics SE proposal needs 33 more sample question titles

Tags: discussion, area51

**Edit:** I wanted people to realize that they only need to write the question *title*, and not the question body itself.

The Mathematical Modeling SE proposal (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling) recently passed a benchmark by reaching the required number of followers.

Unfortunately, very few sample questions have been asked. If you would like a place to direct people with good applied questions that are not on topic here, please consider contributing a few questions and voting on current questions. It requires no commitment.

EDIT: The way Area51 works is that you just write down 5 questions that you think belong on the proposed site (just follow the link to see). Noone answers them; instead, you get 5 votes to decide which of the other questions you would enjoy the most.

Please share any questions you can. Several people have liked this meta post, but noone so far has asked any new questions.

Comment: Perhaps you can search on MO for "modeling", and prune the resulting list for questions to migrate.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger That's a good idea! Each person is limited to 5 questions, so I can't write anymore, but I hope people try it.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger, Brian: Recall that migration is only available to relatively "fresh" question. Anything over 60 days old cannot be migrated by the moderators. Rough calculations show that anything before mid-November 2013 is off game for migration. But it could still be a good sample question perhaps.

Comment: It might make sense to flesh out the post a bit stressing that it is crucial to the proposal moving forward and this becoming an actual site that there is a sufficient number of sample questions with a sufficiently high score; these sample questions are meant to indicate what types of questions *could* be asked on the site and they do not need to be complete questions (but merely headlines) and also they will not be answered. (I do not include it as I was never active on a proposal so might have misunderstood something.)

Comment: Have you seen [scicomp.se]?

Comment: @Kaveh There has been some discussion about this at computational science: http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/376/is-mathematical-modeling-on-topic-here and on area51 (visible at the link in the original post).

Comment: The area51 post actually linked back to another scicomp post: http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/348/computational-modelling-vs-mathematical-modelling . One idea is to go through the proposed questions and comment on those in scicomp's scope.

Comment: Probably a lost cause, but rather than starting a new site, wouldn't it be better if mathematical modelling were more welcome here?

Answer (score 4):

Rather than posting there, I provide here a potential source: If you have sufficient time/interest, then check out the [Mathematical Modeling Handbook](http://www.iitgn.ac.in/mcm/cd/Mathematical%20Modelling%20Handbook/pdf/Modeling_Handbook_Full.pdf) published by COMAP.

The lesson plans/sketches are aimed at secondary school students, but each has a teacher's note immediately following it - "Extending the Model" - written by one of the world's foremost experts in Mathematical Modeling/Applied Mathematics, [Henry Pollak](http://www.maa.org/about-maa/governance/maa-presidents/henry-otto-pollak-1975-1976-maa-president).

As a simple example: pdf Page 81/258 follows a lesson on gauging rainfall, but mentions topics such as Voronoi Diagrams, minimal spanning trees, Kruskal's Method, and Prim's Method.

I'm sure that, of the more than 25 lessons contained therein, there are some which could be adapted to pose sample questions appropriate for what you are seeking.

Separately, you might enjoy the introduction by Pollak, entitled "What is Mathematical Modeling?"

This introduction can also be cited as: Pollak, H. O. (2011). What is Mathematical Modeling?. *Journal of Mathematics Education at Teachers College, 2*(1).

Comment: I am not sure if this is known to you but OP *cannot* (anymore) post any question having reached their limit of 5. So it could be considerably more helpful if you posted one/some there (it is just one phrase/the title). Of course somebody else could still take inspiration, too, so still this is helpful to have.

Comment: @quid Thanks. I saw the OP said this earlier, but I cannot say I have any interest in posting elsewhere. MSE and MO are (more than) enough for me; as you say, if "somebody else" wishes to use the info above, then I will be content.

Answer (score 3):

An additional information (posted in the form of answer): as Area 51 works, it is also very helpful if you just go there and **vote.**

Votes can also be rearranged. It is important to have questions with vote score 10, so it is helpful if you vote on questions with score less than 10.

So if you do not want to get involved, but want to help, this is also one possibility.