# New Stack Exchange site for proof assistants and automatic theorem provers

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, area51

Stack Exchange will soon create the Private Beta site for Proof Assistants and Automatic Theorem Provers. If you want to see what a Stack Exchange site is like in its initial beginnings, want to help shape the future of that site, or just want the silver [beta badge](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta), then I highly recommend getting involved in the Private Beta!

Questions on MathOverflow Meta and Mathematics Meta have been asked about the scope of provers:

- [Questions on Coq](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1672/66334)
- [Tags for automated theorem provers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12069/202425)

Questions on the Theoretical Computer Science Meta have also been asked about the scope of provers:

- [Questions about compilation errors in Coq](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/425/35155)
- [Where should type-theory questions go?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1146/35155)

Similar questions have also been brought up on the Meta for Computer Science SE (a very related site that a lot of the users here use):

- [Are questions about software to solve computer science problems on-topic?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/473/61663)
- [Scope limits on proof assistants (e.g. Coq)](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/52/61663)
- [What part of “Coq: default values for vectors” is on-topic?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/860/61663)

There was also another tangentially related Meta post on Mathematics SE:

- [The problem with proof verification](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29119/202425)

Now there's finally going to be a site catering to that intersection of CS.SE, TCS.SE, MathOverflow and MSE that deals with the topic of computerized provers.

To receive updates about when the site goes live, and when it graduates, and for the opportunity to get rewarded for your early efforts with the site, you can [**go here**](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=NWYwMWI2ODE3MDgzZjk1Mzg4ZjM0MzhkMThlOGU5NWUyNTI4ZjhjOTAxNjAzMzM3ZGM5NDQxMmE2ZWI4NTdjN5SuX0TI5NhFhTPFgY_w1le8uqq_omGyNktdzn76h7sa0), click "sign up" or "login" to make sure your Stack Exchange account is connected, the click "commit".

Often people hesitate to click "commit" because it asks you to promise that you'll post at least 10 questions or answers on the new site, but don't worry about that because most people that click "commit" do not fulfill that commitment, and there's no negative consequences for not committing. However if you do follow through with your commitment you do get rewarded for that.

**[There is already a MathOverflow chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131732/proofassistants-temp) which everyone here is welcome to join if they want to discuss the scope, name, or general structure of the site before it goes live!**

Comment: There is also the [Precognitive badge](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/61/precognitive). But I'd hope that badges are not the main motivation why people joint the site.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think it's too late for them to get that badge, because they'd have to have followed the proposal at the "definition stage" to get that badge, but now that stage is over and we're in the "commitment stage".

Comment: Is the private beta actually open?

Comment: @DavidRoberts "Stack Exchange will soon create the Private Beta site for Proof Assistants and Automatic Theorem Provers" -- it's been 2 days since I said that and the situation is still the same!

Comment: I think the title needs updating, then. It implies the beta's already open, by my reading.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I hadn't noticed that the title had been edited by Federico Poloni to mention the Beta in it. I had never put the word "Beta" in the title, but unfortunately it seem that we don't get notifications when people edit our posts on *Meta*.

Comment: @NikeDattani Sorry, I misread (and saw your comment only now, there was no notification). I still suggest that the title should contain a verb to be more informative, though: what is happening to this new SE site? What is the news here? I'd suggest to add "...to open private beta", or "...will open private beta" if you agree.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni several highly experienced Stack Exchange users have seen the title and even made edits that improved it, but none (other than you) have added an additional verb to it like you suggest. The title is only to catch people's attention while not being deceiving, and the body of the post is where all the information lives. The first sentence of the post "Stack Exchange will soon create the Private Beta site for Proof Assistants and Automatic Theorem Provers" contains the "verb" that you seem to desire.

Comment: Most posts here on Meta similar to yours either have a verb or specify clearly at which stage their site is with the word "proposal": https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1414/, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2430/, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1512/, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1648/, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1426/ (exception https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4321/, currently at -4 score).

Comment: ^ There's bigger things to worry about than that.

Comment: A similar announcement on [math.meta.se]: [New stack exchange site: for interactive theorem provers and automatic theorem provers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34489)